# Correct way to load massive sql table into pyspark

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a table with 1 billion plus rows, that I am looking to basically pull into a dataframe and do a join with another table of lesser size. I have found that this works for a table with a limit under 1 million fairly fast, but over that and there is issues.

Query

```
query = SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM db.table
```

```
def read_query(url, driver, user, password, query, chunk_size):
    return spark.read.format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("driver", driver) \
        .option("user", user) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .option("dbtable", f"({query}) as query_alias") \
        .option("fetchsize", chunk_size) \
        .option("numPartitions", 1000).load()

def partition(iter):
    rows = list(iter)
    print(rows)
    return rows

df_result = read_query(url, driver, user, password, query, chunk_size)
df_result_partitions.rdd.mapPartitions(partition).collect()
```

The issue is loading in the data as df_result is trying to load a billion or so rows into memory.

So my question is:

Is there a way to chunk this SQL query (perhaps write to a file), and then read that into the dataframe? My approach here isn't working, nor is the partitioning because it first needs to load the data. What is the correct way to approach problems like this using pyspark?

Comment: `spark.read` returns a dataframe. Your fetchsize option should be sufficient, don't `collect` or aggregate into python data structures. Are you trying to filter this data down?

Comment: 1. you may avoid printing 1Bn rows; 2. sort each partition on the column used to join with another (small) `df` (that one also should be sorted); 3. consider dumping each sorted partition as `parquet`. That should assure that you do not start always from zero when debugging/testing and helps keep things out of RAM